# My message box show at the same time as main form load visual basic?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, class

i have a coding like this :

```
Private Sub txtNip_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtNip.KeyPress
    If Not (Asc(e.KeyChar) >= Asc("0") And Asc(e.KeyChar) <= Asc("9") Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13) Then
        e.KeyChar = Chr(0)
        MessageBox.Show("Silahkan Masukan Data NIP Dengan Angka...!!")
    ElseIf Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtNip_Enter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtNip.Enter
    cp.P_NIP = Me.txtNip.Text
    If cp.KeypressID() = True Then
        Me.txtNip.Enabled = False
        Me.Fill_Data()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Data Tidak Ditemukan, Nomor Induk Pegawai Yang Anda Masukan Salah..!!")
        Me.Bersih()
    End If
End Sub
```

and class like this :

```
 Public Function KeypressID() As Boolean
        Dim cnn As New SqlConnection(StrConn)
        Dim cmmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim dreader As SqlDataReader
        Dim SQL As String
    SQL = "SP_SELECT_PEGAWAI"

    cnn.Open()
    cmmd = New SqlCommand(SQL, cnn)
    cmmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmmd.Parameters.Clear()
    cmmd.CommandText = SQL
    cmmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@P1", NIP))
    dreader = cmmd.ExecuteReader

    If dreader.Read = True Then
        Dim ImgByte() As Byte = dreader("Foto")
        Dim ImgStr As New System.IO.MemoryStream(ImgByte)
        Me.Foto = Image.FromStream(ImgStr)
        Me.Nama = dreader("Nama")
        Me.Jabatan = dreader("Jabatan")
        Me.Daerah = dreader("Daerah")
        Me.Tsk = dreader("Tsk_Jab")
        Me.PktPns = dreader("Pnk_Pns")
        Me.GolPns = dreader("Gol_Pns")
        Me.TmtPns = dreader("Tmt_Pns")
        Me.Pensiun = dreader("Pensiun")
        Return True
    Else
        Me.Foto = Nothing
        Me.Nama = ""
        Me.Jabatan = ""
        Me.Daerah = ""
        Me.Tsk = Date.Now
        Me.PktPns = ""
        Me.GolPns = ""
        Me.TmtPns = Date.Now
        Me.Pensiun = Date.Now
        Return False
    End If
    cnn.Close()
End Function
```

my problem is, my form load same time as the message box "data tidak ditemukan..". i want that message box out when txtnip didn't found in database and when button ok from messagebox click form will clean itself by calling method bersih(). how to make it right?

Comment: `If dreader.Read = True` => I think this should be `If dreader.HasRows = True`, then you can use `While dreader.Read() ... End While` to iterate the reader and returning `True`. The problem occurred because `KeypressID` method returns false, which indicates `dreader.Read` has `False` value.

Comment: not working Mr. Tetsuya...

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto If the OP is expecting only one record, then `If dreader.Read Then` is fine.  You also wouldn't need HasRows to do the While-Loop.  If there aren't any records, the loop would be skipped.

Comment: Is txtNIP the first control to get focus on the form?  That would fire the Enter event.  If you don't want that, then set the first focused control to something else, or remove the Enter handler and add it in the form's Shown event, so that it doesn't fire too soon.  It's not clear where your NIP value is coming from.

Comment: yes i set focus on txtnip..can u explain more mr. larstech?

Comment: I'm guessing at a lot of things here.  Your txtNip_Enter code doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  This code runs when the txtNip control gets the focus.  Usually a textbox doesn't have a value yet unless you prepopulated yourself in code, but you are running this code immediately when the form loads.  Why do you want to run this code when the control gets the focus?

Comment: mm... okay.. let me explain more my plan... actually this form will show after one of my datagridview cell enter... and then the form show and i want a cursor on txtnip.. so the user can put nip directly without click again. and i want to make a message come when nip doesn't exists in database. the message is "data not found, you put wrong nip" and then "please create data employee first..." like that sir.. i tried put coding form txtnip-enter event on my txtnip-keypress sir... but the message come on first digit nip...

Comment: that actually it supposed to show after 18 digit nip in... that's why i tried to do it in different event sir... and i am still new in here so i just try and error... so that's why maybe that coding is make no sense to you... and that's why i ask... so i will know which part is wrong...

Comment: I would get rid of your KeyPress code and move your Enter code into the TextChanged event of the txtNip control.  Add a `If txtNip.Text.Length = 18 Then`  to it.  The Enter event is for when the cursor "enters" the control, which is not what you want.  A lot of these details should have been in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub txtNip_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtNip.KeyPress
    If Not (Asc(e.KeyChar) >= Asc("0") And Asc(e.KeyChar) <= Asc("9") Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13) Then
        e.KeyChar = Chr(0)
        MessageBox.Show("Silahkan Masukan Data NIP Dengan Angka...!!")
    ElseIf Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then
    End If

    cp.P_NIP = Me.txtNip.Text
    If Me.txtNip.TextLength = 18 And cp.KeypressID() = True Then
        Me.Fill_Data()
        Me.btnAdd.Focus()
    ElseIf Me.txtNip.TextLength = 18 And cp.KeypressID() = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Silahkan Masukan Data...!!")
        Me.Bersih()
    End If
End Sub
```

thanks you Mr. Larchtech...

Comment: Use an "AndAlso" instead of "And" since you only want to evaluate KeypressID when you have 18 characters.